# Audio Stream WiFi to WiFi - Broadcast

Tags: ios, wifi, audio-streaming, broadcast

I have a requirement for an IOS app where a user will start the app, records an audio speech (via device microphone) which would be broadcast to other user on the same network, all this has to be live over wireless connection(WIFI).

I did some research for possible solutions and also tried audio streaming via HTTP URL, but it was not feasible and also involves internet.

I'm looking for your opinions and if it's doable then what is the right approach, (what libraries and API's should I look for)

I'm novice to iOS development, i would really appreciate if you could explain in detail.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: HTTP only involves the internet if you try to connect to a server on the internet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it is doable.  You will need two major components:  A network API to send/receive data , and audio capture and playback API.

For network library, you can try [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket).  It is quite simple to use.

You can use UDP protocol with multicast address.  Even thought you said you wanted to broadcast, but you would be better off using multicast ( send to a group of devices).

For Audio sample how to capture and playback, check out my answer on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573097/ios-audio-unit-remoteio-playback-while-recording/12575037#12575037) .

Comment: Thank you @user523234. Do you know what network compatibilities should be for such a setup. Let's say I have 100 users, and it sounds obvious to me, that even if all of them will be able to connect to WiFi station, the station should be really powerful to make a separate stream to each device. With the suggested approach it sounds, that it works more as a radio - it sends a signal to everyone as a single steam, and therefore the network requirements are much simpler. But I'm not sure if I understand it right, and that is why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @Slabko: In an IP network communication, a device talks (sender) to another device by sending to an IP address that represents the other device (called unicast).  Or sender can send to an IP address that represents a group of receivers (multicast address).  And sender can also send to an IP that represents everybody (broadcast address).  As the receiver device in addition to listen to it own ip, it can also listen to multicast ip, broadcast ip addresses.  The answer to your question, sending to unicast, multicast, broadcast is the same as far as the resource utilization concerned.