# Audio over sockets

Tags: ios, swift, sockets, audio, audio-streaming

## Description

I need to design a solution which will allow two way audio communication via sockets for an iOS App.

Essentially, the App needs to take audio from the device's microphone and pipe it to a destination via a socket while, also reading audio from (presumably a different) socket and play it via the device's speaker (or what ever audio route is established)

## The problem

I've spent several days researching the problem and trying to look for examples which might provide a base line from which I can derive a solution, but I'm just getting more confused.

My basic issue is I don't now if I should start with CoreAudio directly, try using `AVAudioEngine` or if there is some other API available (within AVFoundation or AudioToolbox) which I could use; basically, I can no longer see the forest for the trees.

I've played around with `AVAudioRecorder`, but this seems to be focused on writing content to a file (ok `URL`, but it still doesn't seem appropriate for my needs)

I've begun researching `AVAudioEngine`, but I don't know if it's really the right tool for the job.

## The Question

Essentially I'm looking for some direction (apologies for the broadness of that statement, but I'm completely lost) on the best approach to take and a starting pointing.

I'm primarily concerned with taking the audio from the microphone, probably performing some kind of encoding on it, and then piping it the socket (I'm hoping to be able to use [CocoaAsyncSocket](https://github.com/robbiehanson/CocoaAsyncSocket), so the socket isn't really part of the question, but is provided for context, I just need to get to the point that I have a data packet I can write).

What API would be the best place to start?  CoreAudio, `AVAudioEngine`, some other AVFoundation class/API?

As a side note, would the incoming audio require a different approach, I'm assuming that the concept is the same, but in reverse (read socket, decode packet, write to audio output route)

## Research and side notes

I've basically been searching for "iOS microphone socket" and "iOS microphone streaming" style examples, but I've not yet quite come up with a viable answer/example which seems to be the right direction

- [Get audio from microphone and write it to socket on iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38430805/get-audio-from-microphone-and-write-it-to-socket-on-ios)
- [AVAudioEngine Tutorial for iOS: Getting Started](https://www.raywenderlich.com/5154-avaudioengine-tutorial-for-ios-getting-started)
- [Streaming Audio With Effects Using AVAudioEngine](https://fastlearner.io/blog/streaming-audio-with-effects-using-avaudioengine)
- [Audio Stream WiFi to WiFi - Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18784105/audio-stream-wifi-to-wifi-broadcast), [ios audio unit remoteIO playback while recording](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573097/ios-audio-unit-remoteio-playback-while-recording/12575037#12575037) (and by extension [ios-coreaudio-example](https://code.google.com/archive/p/ios-coreaudio-example/downloads), which seems promising, if a little out of date (>= 2012))

I've also looked at examples of `AVAudioRecorder`, but I'm pretty sure that's a dead end solution for what I need to achieve

I also don't want/need a "preexisting UI", as this should be controlled via the App's custom UI (so something like `AVPlayerViewController` won't help)

I appreciate that this is somewhat broad, I'm not looking for a ready made solution (examples would be nice), but some general direction on the best choices of core APIs I should be focused on that will help me solve the solution.

Comment: What's the larger problem you're trying to solve?  If it's some sort of voice chat application, consider picking up a whole WebRTC stack.  You'll certainly have less control and more bloat, but you won't have to deal with all the complexities of making it work well.

Comment: @brad It’s actually a security camera, but the audio is seperate from the video, we’ll need to connect to it via a direct socket to send/receive audio. I’m just trying to nut out the best point in the api to get started. AVAuduiEngine “seems” like the right place as I will need to encode (and possibly decode) the streams and I need to pipe in/out Data from/to the socket. I've also got a sneaking suspicion that we'd need to customise the decoding step.  Basically, I've only got control over the app side of things